# Null space of matrix is non trivial but contain some variables equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra

During calculating null space from rref matrix some rows are with 1 variable so it give this variable value of zero so the null space of rank deficient matrix be for example {-1,2,0,3,-4,0} my question is how to get rid of zeros in the null space solution and only solve it as basic and free variables so the null space contain any values except zeros for any of its variables thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Do you think you can show a picture of the matrix you're working with?

Comment: Actually my matrix very large sparse matrix in row echelon form , i just wanted to know if there is a general approach i could apply or code it to get to my end result could you help without the need form matrix picture ?

Comment: I just wanted to get the null space without getting zeros in it so all variables are pivot and free so they are related to each other i would be grateful if you help me !